# Disable coc diagnostic popups

Tags: plugin-coc, popup-menu, floating-windows

How do I disable coc diagnostic popups (such as unused variable)?

I have suggestions disabled with `"suggest.autoTrigger": "none"` but I'm struggling to figure out how to disable on-hover diagnostic windows.

I'd still like to be able to see diagnostics in the quickfix window, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diagnostic.enableSign` and `diagnostic.enableMessage` to set whether the signs and messages are shown. `diagnostic.showUnused` sets whether the unused warnings show up.There are probably similar settings in the language server options that affect diagnostics as well.